# Excel-VBA: Winsock TCP/IP connection

Tags: vba, excel, winsock, endianness

I am using Excel/VBA and Winsock to send and receive data via TCP/IP. I have managed to establish a connection and I need to send some data to the server.

The server accepts a specific format for commands:
Each incoming and outcoming command should have the following structure:

- Size of the entire command is placed in the first 4 (four) bytes using big-endian ordering
- The rest ones contain the command body
- Form a command itself by supplying its length in big-endian format in the first 4 bytes.

My string/command to send is in the following format:

```
{C:""EL"",bmId:""43"",inst:""user"",tok:""token""}
```

As I am new to Winsock and just trying to make do, I have problems understanding big-endian conversions, and no matter how I try the server refuses my command.

How would one convert the command above using the specified structure in Excel/VBA? 
More specifically: How do I use VBA convert the command line's size (length, which is an integer e.g 50) to a 4 byte array with big-endian ordering?

Comment: Strings in VBA use two bytes per character, to support Unicode. You might want to use a Byte array instead of a String to create your command.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of byte arrays, I am just not sure how to implement the big-endian ordering and the "size of the command" thing into the "first 4 bytes".